# I am trying to run sails and I am getting Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::1337

Tags: sails.js

I have looked this over and over - there is nothing running on this port. I am running OSX. How can I be getting this error?

Comment: Interesting you're seeing this too. I am on mac os x and have the same problem - but checks like lsof -i :1337 do not reveal the port in use. If i just lift sails using "sails lift --port 1338" it works ok - likewise adding the port option to config.js. Which version of sailsjs are you running? I am using 0.11.3.

Answer (score 0):

Kill you'r nodejs app in the terminal; ps aux | grep node

then kill -9 processID

or better, reboot you'r mac and try to not forget where you sails lift  ;-)

Comment: I have tried rebooting and that didn't work. I don't have any nodejs apps running in the terminal. I tried starting the app with `PORT=<any port number> node index.js`, and no matter what port I set it to, it says it is in use.

Comment: run sails in prod mod to see if it fixed the issue.
    sails lift --prod

this will runs it on port 80

Comment: I changed the port in the config, but I'd still like to know what's causing the issue.

Comment: As I said, you'r 1337 port is used by another process.  Good to know changing port fixed it for you.

Comment: Yes, but nothing is running on 1337

Comment: Had I taken the advise here, I would have killed my Atom text-editor!!  Mind you, rebooting the mac is always a sensible option with issues of this sort ;)  Like the OP, I am also getting the same issue for port 1337 - the problem, as also described in question by OP, is it doesn't appear in port scans as being in use.